# Best practice for Kendo UI and firebase

Tags: kendo-ui, firebase

Is there a suggested / Best practice for integrating Firebase.js with Kendo UI? Angular.js seems to play nicely with Firebase but I cannot figure out how to make Kendo's MVVM work so elegantly.

Comment: While there are no official bindings for Firebase / Kendo UI as there are for Backbone, Angular, Ember, etc., those open-source bindings should provide a nice reference for how you might go about adapting them for Kendo UI. Beyond that, are there any specific problems that you're running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a shot at this. Please check out [kendo-fire](https://github.com/jbristowe/kendo-fire).